# React extremely slow when iterating through JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs

So, Im trying to fetch an JSON API with *fetch()* and iterate through it and render it in Reactjs. It does actually work pretty well with small json lists up to 100 items. But when I try the same thing with a json list of 900 items and upwards, it takes quite a while and the entire site isnt responsive anymore and gets pretty slow.

So what am I doing wrong here and what can I fix to make the site faster?

API.js

```
import _ from 'lodash/array';    
const baseURL = 'https://url.com/api/v1';
class API {
  static getLibrary(user, callback) {
    fetch(`${baseURL}/users/${user}/library`, {
      method: 'get',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      response.json().then((data) => {
        const titles = [];
        const status = [];
        const covers = [];
        const url = [];
        const rating = [];
        const episodesWatched = [];
        const episodesMax = [];
        for (const item in data) {
          titles.push(data[item].library.title);
          status.push(data[item].status);
          covers.push(data[item].library.cover_image);
          url.push(data[item].library.url);
          rating.push(data[item].rating);
          episodesWatched.push(data[item].episodes_watched);
          episodesMax.push(data[item].library.episode_count);
        }
        const library = _.zip(
          titles,
          covers,
          url,
          rating,
          episodesWatched,
          episodesMax
        );
        callback(library);
      });
    });
  }
}
export default API;
```

Index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import API from '../modules/api';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-flexgrid';
import Blazy from 'blazy';
import _ from 'lodash/collection';

class Library extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      library: undefined,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    API.getLibrary(this.props.params.user, (list) => {
      this.setState({
        library: _.sortBy(list, 0),
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    var bLazy = new Blazy();
    if (this.state.library) {
      return (
        <div className="content">
          <Grid>
            <Row>
            {this.state.library.map(function(entry, index) {
              return (
                <Col key={index} xs={6} md={2}>
                  <Card>
                    <CardTitle>{entry[0]}</CardTitle>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                );
            })}
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        Loading
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Library;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear from the code provided where the issue is. Possible culprits:

- Your post-processing logic (`_.zip`, `_.sortBy`) is slow, and causes the UI to lock. I'd start by timing these operations and seeing whether they represent a significant bottleneck.
- You end up with a large number of DOM elements, and this causes the page to appear sluggish. There are various ways to fix this, but pagination or infinite scroll are good top-of-mind approaches. You might try [FixedDataTable](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/) for a good lazy-rendering implementation for large data tables.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering 900 items even directly in the DOM with element.innerHTML can be slow. So you might want to a use a list implementation like this one https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite which would load things into the DOM as you scroll.

Also when you assign key={index} it is a good practice to use unique keys, otherwise React would be confused in case you would reorder or change your list at some point

Comment: Seems like react-infinte does fix the issue, but it has no support for any float and flexgrid containers.. 

So it would break the entire layout.

Comment: You could also try to do paging, there are ready components for that, and it also much simpler to implement

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use 'import' method? React supports it.
Put your json data in one file that ends with '.js'.
YourJsonData.js:

```
export const data = [{title: '',status: '',cover: ''}, {...}, 900 more]
```

Then, in your component file. Component.js:

```
import data from './YourJsonData.js';
console.log(data);
console.log(data.map((item)=> console.log(item.title));

//Then, you use your data which is array of objects
//but you can use Object if you like
```